# Recording of start and end dates of volunteers

Tags: civivolunteer

This is the case: volunteers in a charitable holiday home do 2-week turns in summer and Christmas holidays.
I would like to record their start and end dates.
Where can I register them?

Do I consider volunteers as members?
Or is there a dedicated section in CiviVolunteer?

Thank you.

Comment: you could just record this as an Activity with a custom field for the End Date

Comment: thank you @petednz-fuzion, I thought there was something more specific in the extension. The activities can be anything and it would be better if the participations of the volunteers were separated from the others.

Comment: i have never used the extension but have done 'volunteer' stuff direct via Activities. sorry i can't be of more help, but i don't think Memberships needs to be part of your solution